# Tridion CD client dll versions compatibility

Tags: content-delivery, sites-9, cil, cis

Running Sites 9.0 here and wondering, is it safe to install the latest version of the `Sdl.Web.Delivery` Nuget Package, 11.0.11022? Are they all compatible with the CD of the respective Tridion version or is there a dependency between certain hotfixes of the CIS-es and these packages.

One other thing which is puzzling is [this](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Sdl.Delivery.Cil/) anomaly. Why is 11.0.1097 updated just recently? Why does it have a newer modified date than the latest version?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As usual in Service-Oriented Architectures such as CIL/CIS, the client and server versions are rather loosely coupled.  That is: there is not a 1:1 relationship between the CIL and CIS versions you can use together.

On the other hand, you also cannot expect any CIL version to be 100% compatible with any CIS version. In general, backwards compatibility can be expected (i.e. an older CIL version should work against a newer CIS), but forward compatibility (i.e. using a newer CIL version against an older CIS) is trickier.

This answer is intentionally vague; it makes sense to check with Customer Support if you intent to use two quite different versions of CIL and CIS.

Regarding the versioning scheme used for CD NuGet packages: this is `${major}.${minor}.${patch}${build}`

Note that the patch/SP/CU version and build number are combined into the third part of the semantic version number. Also note that the patch/SP/CU number 0 is not explicit in the third digit. So:

- `11.0.1055` is actually `11.0.0` build `1055`
- `11.0.1097` is actually `11.0.0` build `1097`
- `11.0.11019` is actually `11.0.1` build `1019`.

If there are multiple builds for a given major/minor/patch version, this means that hotfixes were released for that version. The specific version you're wondering about is a recent hotfix for `11.0.0`.

Answer (score 2):

Rick is spot on.

To add some more clarity on that 11.0.1097 release - this was a hotfix for a specific customer. But in general I would use the latest 11.0.1xxxx version available. They are indeed intended to be compatible with all other 11.0.x versions (unless specifically identified by Customer Support).